# Moving the Y position of a legend in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, legend

I've made a legend for my choropleth map inspired off of this:
http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5685876

The challenge is, I want to change the legend's location within my canvas/svg.

```
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
.data(ext_color_domain)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend");

var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", 20)
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
.attr("width", ls_w)
.attr("height", ls_h)
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
.style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", 50)
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
.text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });
```

Changing the "x" location is easy, but the "y" location is the one I'm having trouble with. Why can't I just go `.attr("y", 100, function/*..*/`?

[visual: click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOr18.png)

Comment: You can do `.attr(y, 100)` **or** `.attr(y, function(d,i){ // return some calculation; })`, but not both... Where are you trying to move the legend to?

Comment: I'm trying to move it north. I added a link to a visual in my original comment. This bit: `.attr(y, function(d, i){/*...*/ }` (I think) makes it so each svg stacks on top of each other. Because, when I remove it and just put `.attr(y, 100)`, the legend moves to that location, but all the legend blocks cover one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the way your example code sets the position of the legend.  He is setting each piece of the legend (both `rect` and `text`) independently across the whole svg.  What should be done is that each `rect` and `text` is positioned within the `g` and then the `g` is moved as a group using a `transform`:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)'); //<-- where does the group go

var ls_w = 20,
  ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return (i * ls_h) - 2 * ls_h; //<-- position in group
  })
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(d);
  })
  .style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return (i * ls_h) - ls_h - 4; /<-- position in group
  })
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return legend_labels[i];
  });
```

Full example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hp3iTyI7CFGtFJWHSkuC?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect, that transform is the key I was looking for. Gives me full control over the positioning. Thank you very much.