# using "dy" attribute in d3 to align labels with ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This baffles me. I am trying to use the "dy" attribute on my d3 chart to align the labels with the ticks on this horizontal bar chart.

The documentation says:

> The dy attribute indicates a shift along the y-axis on the position of an element or its content.

Here is the javascript. It pulls the text from the "Question" part of an array.

```
ticks.append("text")
    .attr("class", "ylabel")        
    .attr("dy", "0em")
    .attr("x", -9)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("font-size", "x-small")
    .text(function(d) {  return d['Question']; })
    .call(wrap, 600);
```

Since it's easier to illustrate, when I use "0em", "1em" or "2em" on "dy" I get very different effects. "0em" is too high. "1em" squishes multiple lines together (because of the wrap function), and "2em" wraps the text UPWARDS instead of downwards.

[image]
So how do I shift the labels to align with the ticks on the chart?

### update

by systematically removing lines of javascript in the header, I found that the word_wrap function is pushing this text up and down in weird ways, making it hard to align with the node.

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = -2.0, // ems
        x = text.attr("x"), //<-- include the x!
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy - 2.5 + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight - dy + 3 + "em").text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}

function cwrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        x = text.attr("x"),
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

By using `cwrap` instead of `wrap` I was able to make this work. Both functions are imperfect, and only work with text of a limited size (either 3 lines or 2 lines max). But it solved my problem.

Comment: I think you might also need to set the y position, which would be the bottom of the text. dy is the offset

Comment: put the text/tspan elements in a `g` and position this `g` aligned with the bar. use the DevTools to edit the DOM and look which value works.

Comment: @Katie.Sun is the "y" position relative to the chart or to one tick on the "y-axis" of the chart? I found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785450/moving-the-y-position-of-a-legend-in-d3

Comment: Fairly certain it's relative to the chart. That would be why in the example you showed me the 'y' attribute function starts the same way, or similarly, for both the rectangle and the text components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, the wrap function was forcing text to be misaligned with ticks on my chart in weird ways (including wrapping text upwards if the "dy" offset was "2em"). I had to adjust the wrap function to fix the "dy" problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it has been dX that you need to dynamically set to make things appear relative to others in D3. Here is an example of how I get labels to appear next to nodes on a Force Directed Graph

```
label = label.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("dx", function (d) { return d.radius * 1.25; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; })
            .attr("font-weight", "normal")
            .style("font-size", 10)
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
            .merge(label);
```

The dX value is what you want to base off of what is being drawn, though without seeing the code regarding how the rest of the graph is drawn I'm not sure what attribute of your other elements you should base it off of.

Comment: Great @a-zibuda - I will play around with this. The chart has a lot of elements (as you can see) so it's hard for me to see how the ticks are assigned, looking at the code. The way I read your example `.attr("dy", ".35em")` is that you're moving the text a third of 1em below the mid-line. When I tested my code, that doesn't explain why the wrapping is affected in weird ways when I set a "dy" value.